# Celery autoscale not executing tasks

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

When Celery is receiving a Task, this task never gets executed, just hangs:
These tasks arrive randomly, in very low load.

Celery **3.1.20**

```
[2016-03-02 22:33:08,300: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: catalogue.cluster.deploy_cluster.imbue_cluster[A5C030C4E0]
[2016-03-02 22:33:08,303: INFO/MainProcess] Scaling up 1 processes.
```

After this, nothing happens.

I started celery with supervisord using a shell script:

```
source ~/.profile
CELERY_LOGFILE=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.log
CELERYD_OPTS=" --loglevel=INFO --autoscale=10,5"
cd /usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/conf
exec celery worker -n celeryd@%h -f $CELERY_LOGFILE $CELERYD_OPTS
```

My configuration:

```
CELERYD_CHDIR=settings.filepath
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 360000
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True
BROKER_URL=<rabbitmq>
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True
CELERY_TIMEZONE= "US/Eastern"
CELERY_IMPORTS=("catalogue.cluster.deploy_cluster",
                "tools.deploy_tools",)
```

This is how I call my tasks:

```
celery = Celery()
celery.config_from_object('conf.celeryconfig')
celery.send_task("catalogue.cluster.deploy_cluster.imbue_cluster",
                             kwargs={'configuration': configuration,
                                     'job':           job_instance,
                                     'api_call':      True},
                             task_id=job_instance.reference)


@task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=300, max_retries=5)
def imbue_cluster(...)
```

Similar issues:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.amqp.celery.user/4990
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloudify-users/ANvSv7mV7h4

Comment: how do you know the task does not get executed? what does/does not happen? can you add some logging statements to your task to show if the code is getting run. you don't create result object - why not?

Comment: Tasks remains in RECEIVED state. I do monitor Task via Flower and via my application